# How to give multiple hyperlink to single string

Tags: hyperlink, ms-word

I am of the opinion that giving multiple hyperlink to a single string is not possible in MS word document. I don't have any knowledge of C# but I think after reading [How insert multiple hyperlinks to one comment in MS WORD using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203486/how-insert-multiple-hyperlinks-to-one-comment-in-ms-word-using-c) I just want to clarify weather multiple hyperlink to a single comment is possible or not.

For example I have a "string"
I want to give different hyperlinks like this

```
example.com/s
example.com/t
example.com/r
example.com/i
example.com/n
example.com/g
```

So that I get change to select where I want to go from that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Word, a hyperlink is not a string, it's a field code. Field codes are special objects. It is, therefore, not possible to pass multiple hyperlink objects as part of a string. You can't even pass one hyperlink *object* as part of a string...

You can pass multiple hyperlink strings as a *delimited* string, then "split" the string into an array, loop the array to create multiple hyperlink objects.

If you want to *open* a hyperlink or hyperlinks from code, there is a FollowHyperlink method, as I recall (I'm on a mobile device at the moment, so can't double-check). You can pass a string to that.

Comment: So I was of right opinion that you can not insert multiple hyperlink to a given string.

Comment: I may not understand your question correctly... Can you try to give an example that illustrates what you mean? Do you mean more than one hyperlink at the same position in a Word document?

Comment: Yup. Is it not possible I knew but got confused when you wrote `document.Hyperlinks.Add(rng, ref url, ref missing, ref missing, ref text, ref missing);` in answer I have linked and the title of the question. `How insert multiple hyperlinks to one comment in MS WORD using C#?`

Comment: Is it possible By any means in word to have similar solution. Like when I click on some string I get option where I want to go by listing the hyperlinks.

Comment: @bibadia: Apology if that's breach of rule.

Comment: @Rahul: This sounds like a completely different question: "click on some string...". You really, really need to carefully compose your questions.